# CSS Hover icon reveal animation on button in elementor

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am working on a website and am trying to replicate the hover animation seen here https://www.elegantthemes.com/layouts/business/job-recruiter-contact-page/live-demo.

I am currently developing the project in Elementor and have gotten the icon to appear on hover but I did it with this coding.

```
.btn .elementor-button-icon {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.btn:hover .elementor-button-icon {
    visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- We are seeting aerrow to 15px from right side and to hide `opacity:0`.

```css
  right: calc(0% + 15px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .1s;
```

-To see that movement and roam we are adding 10px extra padding to right side so total 25px `padding-right: calc(15px + 10px);`
-We are seeting aerrow to 5px from right side and to make it visiable `opacity:1`.
-10px because (25px(btn rught padding) - 15px(right side space of aerrow)).

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #29cb8b;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif!important;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #29cb8b;
  transition: .1s;
}

.btn::after {
  content: "\2192";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /*We are seeting aerrow to 15px from right side and to hide opacity 0*/
  right: calc(0% + 15px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .1s;
}

.btn:hover {
  /*To see that movement and roam we are adding 10px extra padding to right side so total 25px*/
  padding-right: calc(15px + 10px);
}

.btn:hover:after {
  /*We are seeting aerrow to 5px from right side and to make it visiable opacity 1*/
  /*10px because (25px(btn rught padding) - 15px(right side space of aerrow))*/
  right: calc(0% + 10px);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn">button</a>
```

Comment: Looks perfect. Sorry i'm not super technical i'm used to no-code options so this is a learning process for me. So I'm working on this website on a stagging link (http://antonior60.sg-host.com/) where I'm trying to replicate it with the use of a button in elementor. I've got some of it there but not adding the padding on the left and moving the button text to the left. I tried to sift through your code and figure out what I could add but I couldn't figure it out. I'm using the "find a job" button as the test subject

Comment: Have you added transition?

Comment: yea I added this to the regular button  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-out;   and this to the hover state transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in;
   padding-left: 20px;

Comment: Just add ```transion:all 0.5s ease-in-out.```